# Creating mac os x software bundle with java processing and python

Tags: python, bundle, processing

I have writing a program using Java Processing.org programming language and it uses some python scripts. Circumstances exist that I cannot change or re write these python scripts in processing.

My problem is I need to bundle this all together and create software bundle for Mac OS X for easy installation. I know there is option in Processing IDE to create software bundles but that will ignores the python files, even so client's machine could not have python installed.

I thought about creating python executable and putting it in to the bundle. Could anyone suggest me better options or software tools to do this.

Regards,
Waruna

Answer (score 1):

Python is shipped with Mac OS X, so your clients should be able to run the scripts.

You do not need to create a "Python executable" as the Python interpreter can just run the `.py` files.

A Mac OS X application bundle (essentially being a folder) contains a folder `Contents` which in turn contains the binary application files, resources, etc.  You can place your `.py` files within the `.app` bundle and call them from within your Java code.

The bundle documentation is available here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I'm using third party python module, that is my I'm having this problem. I don't want to tell client to go to command line and install that python module.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to deliver some Python modules in a user friendly manner (i.e., without the end users having to know about easy_install or whatever).

I am no expert in this area, but it seems to me like you're trying to solve a similar problem that the Mercurial people solved, you may want to have a look at what they did. This is how Mercurial is delivered on the Mac - http://mercurial.berkwood.com/.